# xcdatamodeld issue with adding new fields

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a a Cars.xcdatamodeld (used for a light migration) that has my main entity Cars2.xcdatamodel (it is the entity selected)
when i try to add a field to my Cars2, i am not permited to add a field that starts with a upper scale letter (although there are fields that are with an upper scale).

When i try:

```
Cars *CS = (NeonSigns *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cars" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]; 
CS.newImageUrl = @"www.xrt.ro/a.jpg"
```

where .newImageUrl is a field i just added, the compiler doesn't recognize newImageUrl (although it recognizes the other fields) . Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

NextStep naming conventions dictate that class definitions begin with a capital letter and methods and properties begin with lower case letters. Core Data depends upon those conventions when translating between the different representations of information in the Core Data stack, model definitions, back end stores, and runtime objects. Core Data maps entities to Objective C classes and attributes to properties of those classes. You can confuse Core Data when you deviate from this naming convention.